# Is this sentence impolite?

Tags: politeness

I came across this sentence while I reading some questions randomly. The question starts with this sentence:

> This is a bit of a noob question so bear with me.

Obviously, the user wants to excuse that he is a beginner and he might say something non-sense.
But to say, 'bear with me' in the imperative, isn't the user bit rude?
I feel like he is ordering to bear his ignorance. But why do I have to?

Wouldn't he need to say 'please' to be more polite?

> This is a bit of a noob question so bear with me, please.

Do I need to feel a bit uneasy?
Or is the original sentence acceptable as the internet culture?

Comment: I think this is venturing into the realm of opinion. The user is clearly striking an informal and self-deprecatory tone, and I don't think saying *please* adds or removes much, given that.

Comment: [***...please** bear with me...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22please+bear+with+me%22) But there are plenty of hits in Google Books [*without* the word "please".](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01cY9f4Qzv9p2hhXnlScspUvWrMXA%3A1594652753889&ei=UXgMX8DsNcnQ6QSWjYK4DA&q=%22bear+with+me%22+-%22please+bear+with+me%22&oq=%22bear+with+me%22+-%22please+bear+with+me%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...61080.68718.0.69503.10.10.0.0.0.0.231.1467.2j7j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.YyO9YSyCMi8)

Comment: @choster I simply don't know how to interpret the sentence. I feel difficulty often with the attitude of the conversation. Anyway, from your comment, I feel there is no clear cut answer.

Comment: Not at all rude. Just stating a situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why do I have to?

You actually don’t, you could choose to not read their question.

Similarly, if a shopkeeper said that to you, you could always take your business elsewhere.

The way “bear with me” is usually interpreted is as a plea. I guess this is such a common interpretation that the word “please” is not seen as necessary, though it would be used in many cases; it’s certainly technically more polite to say “please”, but not saying it would not be interpreted as impolite.